# Simple one-hot encoder

Tags: python, numpy

Because neither sklearn nor Pandas provide a straightforward and complete one-hot encoder, I decided to write one myself. Both Pandas and sklearn do have an encoder with no option to decode, and the `sklearn.LabelEncoder` that has the decoding only produces that, labels.

Here's the class:

```
import numpy as np

class OneHotEncoder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.unq = np.array([])
        self.n_features = len(self.unq)

    def set_unq(self, unq):
        self.unq = unq
        self.n_features = len(unq)

    @staticmethod
    def _assure(cond, msg):
        if not cond:
            raise ValueError(msg)

    def fit_transform(self, np_arr):
        """
        From categories to one-hot encoding. Calculate unique occurences.
        :param np_arr: categorical data of shape (samples, 1)
        :return: one-hot encoding with shape (sample, categories)
        """
        self._assure(np_arr.shape[-1] == 1, 'Last axis must be length 1.')
        unq, idx = np.unique(np_arr, return_inverse=True)
        self.set_unq(unq)

        arr = np.zeros((len(idx), len(self.unq)))
        arr[range(len(idx)), idx] = 1
        return arr

    def transform(self, np_arr):
        """
        From categories to one-hot encoding based on previous samples.
        :param np_arr: categorical data of shape (samples, 1)
        :return: one-hot encoding with shape (sample, categories)
        """
        self._assure(np_arr.shape[-1] == 1, 'Last axis must be length 1.')
        arr = np.argwhere(self.unq == np_arr)[:, 1]
        zr = np.zeros((len(arr), len(self.unq)))
        zr[range(len(arr)), arr] = 1
        return zr

    def fit_transform_to_labels(self, np_arr):
        """
        From categories to label values. Calculate unique occurences.
        :param np_arr: categorical data of shape (samples, 1)
        :return: label values with shape (sample, 1)
        """
        self._assure(np_arr.shape[-1] == 1, 'Last axis must be length 1.')
        unq, idx = np.unique(np_arr, return_inverse=True)
        self.set_unq(unq)
        return idx.reshape(-1, 1)

    def transform_to_labels(self, np_arr):
        """
        From categories to label values based on previous samples.
        :param np_arr: categorical data of shape (samples, 1)
        :return: label values with shape (sample, 1)
        """
        self._assure(np_arr.shape[-1] == 1, 'Last axis must be length 1.')
        arr = np.argwhere(self.unq == np_arr)
        return arr[:, 1:2]

    def transform_from_labels(self, np_arr):
        """
        From label values to one-hot encoding.
        :param np_arr: label values of shape (samples, 1)
        :return: one-hot encoding with shape (samples, categories)
        """
        self._assure(np_arr.shape[-1] == 1, 'Last axis must be length 1.')
        arr = np.zeros((len(np_arr), len(self.unq)))
        arr[range(len(arr)), np_arr.reshape(-1)] = 1
        return arr

    def inverse_from_labels(self, np_arr):
        """
        From label values to original categorical values.
        :param np_arr: label values of shape (samples, 1)
        :return: original categorical values with shape (samples, 1)
        """
        self._assure(np_arr.shape[-1] == 1, 'Last axis must be length 1.')
        return self.unq[np_arr]

    def inverse_to_lables(self, np_arr):
        """
        From one-hot encoding to label values.
        :param np_arr: one-hot encoding of shape (samples, categories)
        :return: label values with shape (samples, 1)
        """
        self._assure(np_arr.shape[-1] == len(self.unq), 'Inverting array must be same length as available labels.')
        return np.argmax(np_arr, axis=-1).reshape(-1, 1)

    def inverse(self, np_arr):
        """
        From one-hot encoding to original categorical values.
        :param np_arr: one-hot encoding of shape (samples, categories)
        :return: original categorical values with shape (samples, 1)
        """
        self._assure(np_arr.shape[-1] == len(self.unq), 'Inverting array must be same length as available labels.')
        return self.inverse_from_labels(np.argmax(np_arr, axis=-1).reshape(-1, 1))
```

So in short, this class combines the functionality of `sklearn.LabelEncoder` and `sklearn.OneHotEncoder`. The assertions are a bit redundant, I just like to keep my vectors as column vectors.

This class does work.

- Is it missing something in terms of functionality or safety?
- Could it be expanded to some different cases I haven't yet taken into account?

Here's a small snippet of using the class:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,3,2,1]).reshape(-1, 1)
oh = OneHotEncoder()
labs = oh.fit_transform_to_labels(a)
encoded = oh.transform_from_labels(labs)
decoded = oh.inverse(encoded)
```

Comment: Revised version below as an answer for anyone who's interested!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## variable naming

`np_arr` is a bad name for a variable, especially if you use it in multiple places, each with a different meaning. Name the part, so for example in `fit_transform`, `samples` is a better name.
`self.unq` is also unclear, I would replace it with `self._categories`

## `_assure`

why not just use the built-in `assert`. If you really want to raise a `ValueError` instead of an `AssertionError`, make it a top-level function instead of putting it on the class.

## @property

instead of

```
class OneHotEncoder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.unq = np.array([])
        self.n_features = len(self.unq)

    def set_unq(self, unq):
        self.unq = unq
        self.n_features = len(unq)
```

you can use the [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator

```
class OneHotEncoder:
    def __init__(self):
        self._categories = None

    @property
    def categories(self):
        assert self._categories is not None, 'Fit the encoder first'
        return self._categories

    @categories.setter
    def categories(self, categories):
        self._categories = categories

    @property
    def n_features(self):
        return len(self.categories)
```

and then where you would use `self.set_unq(unq)`, you can do `self.categories = unq`

## shape

Is there any particular reason why the last axis must be length 1? I find shape `(n_samples,)` more intuitive than `(n_samples, 1)`

## tests

Did you test this code? 
in your  example code, `encoded` is

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

so something went wrong there (probably to do with the extra dimension).

## dtype

For the encoded array, I would use `dtype=bool`, since it's a series of flags.

## examples

including examples in the docstring might make it clearer what the goal of the method is

## DRY

The code to fit the `np_arr` is used in 2 methods, you can refactor that out

In `inverse`, you have the code `np.argmax(np_arr, axis=-1).reshape(-1, 1)`, which is exactly what `inverse_to_lables` does, so use that method instead of repeating the code

## class

Why do you need a class for this? All you use it for is passing around the categories of the encoding. passing them around as arguments seems a lot easier, then these 4 methods do about the same as your class

```
def encode_index(index, n_categories: int=None):
    if n_categories is None:
        n_categories = len(np.unique(index))
    shape = (len(index), n_categories)
    encoding = np.zeros(shape, dtype=bool)
    encoding[range(len(index)), index] = True
    return encoding
```

takes a list of integers, and turns it into the encoded form

```
encode_index([0,1,2,1])
```

> ```
> array([[ True, False, False],
>        [False,  True, False],
>        [False, False,  True],
>        [False,  True, False]])
> ```

and it's inverse:

```
def decode_index(encoding):
    return np.argmax(encoding, axis=-1)
```

the higher-level encoding can be done like this:

```
def encode(samples, categories=None):
    cat, index = np.unique(samples, return_inverse=True)
    categories = categories if categories is not None else cat
    encoding = encode_index(index, len(categories))
    return encoding, categories

encode(list('abdefea'))
```

> ```
> (array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
>         [False,  True, False, False, False],
>         [False, False,  True, False, False],
>         [False, False, False,  True, False],
>         [False, False, False, False,  True],
>         [False, False, False,  True, False],
>         [ True, False, False, False, False]]),
>  array(['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f'], dtype='<U1'))
> ```

and the inverse:

```
def decode(encoding, categories):
    index = decode_index(encoding)
    return categories[index]
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! I learned a lot, expecially about the decorator! I can't believe I managed to not include the fix to the post. I did test, and fix the very bug you pointed out but left it in the local code only... But to respond: I've heard that [assertions are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13534633/7089239) at least in running code. As I said, the shape assertion is just to my own liking, so that the array returned has the same dimensions e.g. `(samples, 1) -> (samples, features)` but I understand the point and perhaps it would be good to make it more general.

Comment: Or even accept multiple categories in the last axis! Hey that's a neat idea :D Using a class is solely for keeping the `features` state and more clearly bundling the functionality together, but functions and a module might work too. Cheers! Please do further disagree if you feel that's warranted.

Answer (score 0):

#### Reply to self: an improved version

Here's an improved version for anyone who's interested. I managed to simplify it in lots of ways. Many suggestions from the answer were implemented, but I decided to keep the class form. Most notably I decided to ditch the assertion that the first axis should have length 1, allowing for a more general encoding scheme (still only the last axis encoded though).

```
class OneHotEncoder:
    """
    Simple one-hot encoder.

    Does not handle unseen categories: will default to the first category.
    Does not invert all-zero arrays: will default to the first category.
    Does not handle nan data.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._categories = None

    @property
    def categories(self) -> np.ndarray:
        if self._categories is None:
            raise ValueError('Encoder not fitted!')
        return self._categories

    @categories.setter
    def categories(self, categories) -> None:
        self._categories = categories

    @property
    def n_features(self) -> int:
        return len(self.categories)

    def fit(self, categories: np.ndarray) -> None:
        self.categories = np.unique(categories)

    def transform(self, samples: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        return self.transform_from_labels(self.transform_to_labels(samples))

    def transform_to_labels(self, samples: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        arr = np.argwhere(self.categories == samples.reshape(-1, 1))
        labels = np.zeros((samples.size,), dtype=int)
        labels[arr[:, 0]] = arr[:, 1]
        return labels.reshape(samples.shape)

    def transform_from_labels(self, labels: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        return np.eye(self.n_features)[labels]

    def inverse_from_labels(self, labels: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        return self.categories[labels]

    @staticmethod
    def inverse_to_labels(encoded: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        return np.argmax(encoded, axis=-1)

    def inverse(self, encoded: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        return self.inverse_from_labels(self.inverse_to_labels(encoded))
```

Next I made a subclass for some more demanding tasks.

```
class NanHotEncoder(OneHotEncoder):
    """
    Extension to the simple OneHotEncoder.

    Does handle NaN data, ignores unseen categories (all zero) and inverts all zero rows.
    Only accepts and returns 1-dimensional data (pd.Series) as samples (categories).
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def _mask_assign(shape: tuple, mask: np.ndarray, values: np.ndarray, init: float=np.nan) -> np.ndarray:
        array = np.full(shape, init)
        array[mask] = values
        return array

    def transform_from_labels(self, labels: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        nans = np.isnan(labels)
        encoded = super(NanHotEncoder, self).transform_from_labels(labels[~nans].astype(int))
        return self._mask_assign(labels.shape + (self.n_features,), ~nans, encoded, init=0)

    def inverse_to_lables(self, encoded: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        nans = np.sum(encoded, axis=-1) == 0
        inverted = super(NanHotEncoder, self).inverse_to_labels(encoded[~nans].astype(int))
        return self._mask_assign(encoded.shape[:-1], ~nans, inverted)

    def transform_to_labels(self, samples: pd.Series) -> np.ndarray:
        mask = samples.isnull() | ~samples.isin(self.categories)
        labels = super(NanHotEncoder, self).transform_to_labels(samples[~mask].values)
        return self._mask_assign(samples.values.shape, ~mask.values, labels)

    def inverse_from_labels(self, labels: np.ndarray) -> pd.Series:
        series = pd.Series(labels.ravel())
        inverted = super(NanHotEncoder, self).inverse_from_labels(series.dropna().values.astype(int))
        series[~series.isnull()] = inverted
        return series

    def transform(self, samples: pd.Series) -> np.ndarray:
        return self.transform_from_labels(self.transform_to_labels(samples))

    def inverse(self, encoded: np.ndarray) -> pd.Series:
        return self.inverse_from_labels(self.inverse_to_labels(encoded))
```

Here's also a basic test suite to validate the functionality.

```
import unittest
from encoders import OneHotEncoder, NanHotEncoder

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def array_equal(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return (a == b) | ((a != a) & (b != b))


class TestOneHotEncoder(unittest.TestCase):
    str_categories = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

    def setUp(self):
        self.oh = OneHotEncoder()
        self.oh.fit(self.str_categories)

    def test_fit(self):
        self.assertTrue(np.all(self.str_categories == self.oh.categories))

    def test_transform_to_labels(self):
        samples = np.array([[['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']], [['d', 'd'], ['a', 'd']]])
        result = np.array([[[0, 2], [1, 2]], [[3, 3], [0, 3]]])
        self.assertTrue(np.all(self.oh.transform_to_labels(samples) == result))

    def test_transform_from_labels(self):
        labels = np.array([[0, 2], [1, 3]])
        result = np.array([[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]], [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]])
        self.assertTrue(np.all(self.oh.transform_from_labels(labels) == result))

    def test_inverse_from_labels(self):
        labels = np.array([[[0, 2], [1, 2]], [[3, 3], [0, 3]]])
        result = np.array([[['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']], [['d', 'd'], ['a', 'd']]])
        self.assertTrue(np.all(self.oh.inverse_from_labels(labels) == result))

    def test_inverse_to_labels(self):
        encoded = np.array([[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]], [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]])
        result = np.array([[0, 2], [1, 3]])
        self.assertTrue(np.all(self.oh.inverse_to_labels(encoded) == result))


class TestNanHotEncoder(unittest.TestCase):
    categories = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

    def setUp(self):
        self.nh = NanHotEncoder()
        self.nh.fit(self.categories)

    def test_transform_to_labels(self):
        samples = pd.Series(['a', 'c', np.nan, 'c', 'd', np.nan, 'a', 'd'])
        result = np.array([0, 2, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan, 0, 3])
        self.assertTrue(np.all(array_equal(self.nh.transform_to_labels(samples), result)))

    def test_transform_from_labels(self):
        labels = np.array([[0, np.nan], [np.nan, 3]])
        result = np.array([[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]])
        self.assertTrue(np.all(array_equal(self.nh.transform_from_labels(labels), result)))

    def test_inverse_from_labels(self):
        labels = np.array([0, 2, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan, 0, 3])
        result = pd.Series(['a', 'c', np.nan, 'c', 'd', np.nan, 'a', 'd'])
        self.assertTrue(self.nh.inverse_from_labels(labels).equals(result))

    def test_inverse_to_labels(self):
        encoded = np.array([[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]])
        result = np.array([[0, np.nan], [np.nan, 3]])
        self.assertTrue(np.all(array_equal(self.nh.inverse_to_lables(encoded), result)))

    def test_novel_classes(self):
        samples = pd.Series(['a', 'f', np.nan, 'd'])
        result = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0],  [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
        self.assertTrue(np.all(array_equal(self.nh.transform(samples), result)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    oh_test = TestOneHotEncoder()
    nh_test = TestNanHotEncoder()
    test = unittest.TestSuite()
    test.addTests([oh_test, nh_test])
    res = unittest.TestResult()
    test.run(res)
```

This was a great learning experience. It's still not finished though. It'd be nice to be able to handle the general n-dimensional or at least the common 2D case with the NanHotEncoder as well. But time will tell, perhaps I'll edit this answer.

Cheers!